# Problems with creating an impl-block using a macro in Rust

Tags: generics, macros, rust

I want to create a macro generating a given formatter (`Display`, `Debug`,...) for a struct containing a single generic type.

```
macro_rules! create_formatter {
    ($type_name:ident<$gen_param:ident>, $trait:path) => {
        impl<$gen_param: $trait> $trait for $type_name<$gen_param> {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
                // isn't yet implemented 
            }
        }
    };
}
```

When I call the macro later in the code (`create_formatter!(MyStruct<T>, std::fmt::Display);`), the compiler gives the following feedback:

```
error: expected one of `,`, `=`, `>`, or `?`, found `std::fmt::Display`
--> test.rs:6:26
 |
6|         impl<$gen_param: $trait> $trait for $type_name<$gen_param> {
 |                          ^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does work if you use `ident` for the fragment specifier used for the trait bound. (That also means you need to call it with `Display` and add `use std::fmt::Display;`). But I am not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem mysterious!  It seems the problem is down to the way that the output of a macro is parsed: since it's been partly pre-parsed as a `path` during the macro processing, it no longer matches the parse rule for a trait bound.  There was a [bug raised a few weeks ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38461) about this.

However, there is good news - [it's been fixed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38279)!  The example actually works in the beta or nightly compilers ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f9389f27e260f0bc429670afa0a1f42&version=beta&backtrace=0)), though note I had to rename `$trait` to `$t` as `trait` is a keyword.